# PHP using extract() to pass array values as variables and display it on a page

Tags: php, function

I am attempting to create a `view($path,$data)` function in `php` the main functionality is include a specific file from the directory and pass in data/variable into that page, i managed to create `$path` and was able to include the define path, now my next step is pass in the `$data` values into my included page, and want to convert each array label as a variable.

My php class is below `classes.php`.

```
define("SITE_NAME", "process");

 class helpers {


        public function view($path, $data) 
        {

            $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].SITE_NAME."/";

            include($dir.$path.".php");

            return extract($data);



        }  

}
```

On my index.php

```
require_once('classes.php');

$helper = new Helpers();

$data['title'] = "My Test";
$data['test'] = "test1";

$helper->view('test',$data);
```

So now on my test.php i am tring to echo `$title` which i assuming it will return the value of `My Test`, to test if i am getting the values from `index.php` i was able to output the `$data` using `print_r`

`Array ( [title] => My Test [test] => test1 )`

Any advice how can i achieve? i was trying the `extract()` function but don't know if my syntax is correct.Thanks in advance!

Comment: i don't see any problem with your code. If there's error, i think its all good ;)

Comment: Yes $data.title would be good but i need to convert the title as a new variable which is $title.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is there anyway to convert `$data['title']` into just `$title` so i can `echo $title` i was looking at the syntax of `extract(array,extract_rules,prefix) ` i think i am missing the two parameters.

Comment: simple return the `$data` and in view simple apply the `extract($data);`

Comment: @JYoThI can you post a answer so i can reference it, it will help a lot thanks!

Comment: Yeah i posted my answer @KaoriYui

Comment: Place the extract before the include, and your array elements will be available as variables within the view.  If you want to capture the view as a rendered string, use output buffering as advised by @ArtisticPhoenix below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because return is limited to only one value.

By extracting it you are taking one value `the array` and splitting it into many.

Personally I avoid using things like `extract` and `$$var` in my code as it destroys my IDE and make readability near impossible.  That said, in this case it does make sense to use it, because it's within a limited scope which limits the possibility of accidentally overriding another variable unintentionally.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

> A function **can not** return **multiple values**, but similar results can be obtained by returning an array.

AND

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

> extract — Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

symbol table ~ scope

Further

> **Return Values:** Returns the number of variables successfully imported
>   into the symbol table

```
public function view($path, $data)
{

    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].SITE_NAME."/";

    include($dir.$path.".php");
    return extract($data); //returns the variables successfully imported from $data
}
```

.

As you can see once you call return, that ends the execution of the current function, and closes that scope. You will have to re-arrange these, so the variable assignment takes place first.

I'm assuming the included file in the method is something like this, it wasn't in the OP.

```
    <h1><?= $title; ?></h1>
```

You don't technically need to return anything because the HTML will naturally be caught by the output buffer and displayed when the script finishes executing.  However, that is not very clean.  The correct way is to take control of the output buffer like this:

```
    public function view($path, $data) 
    {
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].SITE_NAME."/";

        extract($data); //variables must exist before importing where they are used.
        ob_start();
        include($dir.$path.".php"); //capture this output
        $view = ob_get_clean();
       return $view;
    }  

   $out = $helper->view('test',$data); //out now contains the HTML output from the included file.
```

Then you can `echo` it out.  IMO this is better because you could then insert that HTML output into another data array and pipe it into another template. Which is useful for things like a re-usable header or footer or nav bar etc..

Consider this

```
$head['page_title'] = "My Test";
$body['head'] = $helper->view('header',$head); //create head and assign to body

$body['name'] = 'John Smith';
echo $helper->view('body',$body); //create body (with head inserted) and echo
```

And header.php

```
<title><?= $page_title; ?></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And body.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?= $head; ?>
    </head> 
    <body>
       <p><?= $name; ?></p>
    </body> 
 </html>
```

The output would now be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Test</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>
     <p>John Smith</p>
  </body>   
</html>
```

Now both pages are combined into one, that is output. You could take this to whatever level of re-usability you wanted, but it would save you a ton of typing and make maintaining the views way easier.

But, as I said you can just as simply allow it to output naturally

```
    public function view($path, $data) 
    {
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].SITE_NAME."/";

        extract($data); //variables must exist before importing where they are used.
        include($dir.$path.".php"); //capture this output
    } 
    //outputs when script is done.
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help OP achieve what needed?

Comment: @cornel.raiu - hold your horses

Comment: Again. Explain why it is bad to use it that way and give a better solution :) you are only explaining why it.s bad

Comment: it's not bad it makes no logical sense, structure wise its not possible to do that the scope is different, besides my wife just walked in and started yacking to me, so AS I SAID hold your horses.  If you have a better solution your free to post your own answer, instead of jumping me..

Comment: I am on my phone playing with my daughter. I can't post a solution now. But I would definitely post a solution that would actually help the OP correct the initial code

Comment: To me you comments were, well a bit rude.

Comment: Sorry. That was not my intention

Comment: @cornel.raiu This solution is exactly what the OP needs to make vars available to an included file, especially the output buffering example. @ArtisticPhoenix -- I don't like `extract` myself, but I've grown to comment my views with what they expect using phpDoc comments like `/** @var type $extractedVariable */`.  My IDE seems to like it fine as long as I remain in that file.

Comment: Satisfied?  I have more then enough PHP experience to answer a simple question like this.  To be honest there should be a 10 minute time on SO that a answer cannot be down voted on to allow for edits.  Sometimes people accidentally click submit.  Sometimes the question is not clear and trying to get that info is more involved then what a comment can provide.

Comment: I also think it's a good approach to first explain what the OP did wrong and then show them how to fix it.  Just posting an answer teaches them nothing.

Comment: @KaoriYui - do you plan to make every view a self contained page, or would you like to reuse parts of existing views.  if you want to reuse parts then use the output buffering.  I can put an example of that in the answer if you want.

Comment: That looks nice :) and I upvoted the solution. What IDE do you use?

Comment: Eclipse PDT sense version 3.2( released Callisto 30 June 2006 v3.2 ), now I have neon at work and mars at home, should probably update it.  That should tell you how long I been coding.

Comment: PS I used to use Notepad++ for about 2 years before that :-/.  I remember fixing PHP4 constructors and fixing `ereg` calls in my early days, that was fun.  And `simplePie` for rounded corners in IE6 lol.

Comment: @cornel.raiu - I'm a bit rusty when it comes to mixed php/html. I actually been working on a HTML Parser/Lexer/Compiler for HTML templates. it's like 40% done.  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo/tree/master/Evo/App/Plugin

Comment: I recommend phpstorm. It rocks in all possible ways.  Db, code inspector, mixed php/html/js, version control systems embeded ... you can test it for 30 days. It really rocks. I have about 12 years in the industry now and have been using phpstorm for the last 3 years.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the guys at intellij are awesome and very developer oriented

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for your help, this is my first time attempting this type of php code and i like to learn more, i will try the output buffering my self :)

Comment: @cornel.raiu - phpStorm its also 100 bucks ( last I looked), I could get my boss to pay for it but Eclipse works just fine and I am used to it; Also I do some JAVA